# Unable to create database encryption key

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm learning database encryption and i'm actualy confuse about a mistake that hapen when i try to enable encryption on my database.

So here it is what i do to create the certificate

```
    /* Certificat de base de données */

    CREATE CERTIFICATE certTestEncryption
    WITH SUBJECT='Certificat TestEncryption';

    /* Chiffrage de la BDD */

    SELECT * FROM sys.certificates
```

And there it is what i got :
[image: certificat of my database 'testEncryption']

So my certificate actually exist.

But when i try to execute this statement :

```
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM=AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE certTestEncryption;
```

It is not working at all and give me the folowing error message :

> Cannot find the certificate "certTestEncryption" because it does not
>   exist or you do not have authorization.

So i try this one

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM=AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE certTestEncryption;
```

But it still give me the same error as evoked prior.

I have also try to encryption by asymmetric key :

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM=AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER ASYMMETRIC KEY asymKey;
```

It still give me this error : 
Unable to find the asymmetric key "asymmetricKey" because it does not exist or you do not have authorization.

Even if the asymmetric key actually exist :
[image: Database encryption by asymmetric key]

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting? I *assume* all the above statements are being run in the context of the same database?

Comment: Hello, yes all the statements are runing in the context of the same db.
Syntax error is : 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 67
Incorrect syntax to'sa'.

Comment: Oh, that because to execute as a different user/login is `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';` **prior** to the batch(es) you want to run as a different `LOGIN` (replace `LOGIN` with `USER` for user credentials). After you have run the relevant statements, you use `REVERT` to revert them. I suggest putting `EXECUTE AS` and `REVERT` is separate batches to the batch you are running as a different user as well.

Comment: I try EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';
And then after having execute this statement i try again the 
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM=AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE certTestEncryption;
Wich fail again for the same reason than previously ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly found the solution !
I was created the certificate on the database that i want to encrypt.
But that's not how it work.

If you got the same problem, do as follow

```
USE MASTER;
CREATE MASTER KEY
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='password';
```

> The database master key is encrypted by the service master key.
>   The database master key encrypt every key and certificate inside the specifyed
>   database (wich is currently 'master' database).

Then you **stay into master database** and execute the following statement

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE certName
[Encryption by password='password']
WITH SUBJECT='your Subject'
```

> The certificate is created into the master database.
>   The certificate is encrypted by default with the database main master key (see previous > paragraph), but you can change that by using 'ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD...'

Finaly you go to the database where you cant to activate encryption
(Be sure to backup certificate and master database's key)

```
USE nameOfYourDB;
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM=[AES_128, AES_192, AES_258...]
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER [CERTIFICATE nameOfYourCertificate|ASYMMETRIC KEY nameOfAsymmetricKey];

ALTER DATABASE nameOfYourDB
SET ENCRYPTION ON;
```

That's it. You have to create the certificate/asymmetric key on the database master to be able to use it on an other database.

I hope it'll help other people !

[Link](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-transparent-data-encryption-tde-in-sql-server/) of the website that helped me to found the solution

Comment: I am searching for a way to put the cert/asym key into the database itself, then have the client actually supply us with a password when they access it, which we use to "open" the master key. This one master key in the master database seems like nonsense to me. Much less secure than keeping the 2nd password with the client and optionally offsite as a backup.